# jquery function event listener breaking first part of function

Tags: jquery, event-listener

I have a function with a event listener that then prompts another function.  Before the event listener the function worked perfectly fine.  What's suppose to happen is text is suppose to get loaded into their respective divs, and then when they finish there's suppose to be an animation function that happens.  The animation function causes the text loading to be skipped for some reason.

Here is the JS BIN set up http://jsbin.com/umohoj/11/edit

and here it is on url for the .load (even though they don't work with the eventlistner)

http://www.klossal.com/b_test.html

here is a working example of just the loads with no animations:

http://www.klossal.com/b_testa.html

here is a working example of the animations with the loads as one function, instead of the animations waiting for the loads to finish, which is what I'd like to have happen because the loads need to finish for some of the calculations in the animations to work correctly.

http://www.klossal.com/b_testb.html

here is the code with the event listener that for some reason prevents the loads from working:

```
$(".name").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  $('#photo_850').empty();

  $("<img>", { src: id + ".jpg" }).prependTo("#photo_850");

  $("#name_850").load(id +"_name.txt");

  $("#credentials_850").load(id +"_credentials.txt");

  $("#bio_850_text").load(id +"_bio.txt", function() {
    $("#bio_850_img").css({
    marginTop: ($("#bio_850_text").innerHeight() /2) -   
    ($("#bio_850_img").height() / 2)
    });                                                                     
  });

  $("#edu_850_text").load(id +"_edu.txt", function() {
    $("#edu_850_img").css({
    marginTop: ($("#edu_850_text").innerHeight() /2) -   
    ($("#edu_850_img").height() / 2)
    });                                                                     
  });

  $("#contact_850_text").load(id +"_contact.txt", function() {
    $("#contact_850_img").css({
    marginTop: ($("#contact_850_text").innerHeight() /2) -   
    ($("#contact_850_img").height() / 2)
    });                                                                     
  });






}, function() {




  $("#container_1").animate({
     height: 87 + $("#box_2_850").height() + $("#box_3_850").height() +     
$("#box_4_850").height()
  }, 300);

  $("#container_1_txt").animate({
     "margin-top": $("#container_1_txt").innerHeight() * -1
  }, 300);

    $("#box_1_850").delay(160).animate({
     marginTop: 15
  }, 300);

    $("#box_2_850").delay(330).animate({
     marginTop: 0
  }, 450);  

    $("#box_3_850").delay(450).animate({
     marginTop: 0
  }, 450);  

    $("#box_4_850").delay(570).animate({
     marginTop: 0
  }, 450); 










                 });
```

Comment: Can you please stup jsfiddle for this? You'll need to include your HTML script as well; thanks...

Comment: updated the question for you

Comment: Do you have a working version without the animations?

Comment: I gather the callback just isnt working the way you intend it to, and is pretty much causing a glitch somewhere.

Comment: I moved the whole animation sequence to its own function and tried using a callback with just the function name.

Comment: What I am thinking is that because it is a chained callback, it is not recognizing when the the load functions are complete

Comment: The load functions themselves can take a callback argument, but I don't think the click callback can

Comment: when you moved the animation do it's own function did that work?

Comment: I can only see one way out of this...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19616/discussion-between-videsignz-and-loriensleafs)

Comment: Don't let databases scare you...they are about as easy as html...haha

Comment: Works great on my phone too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive research ;) I have a solution!  Haha

```
$("#container_1").css({
  'height': $("#container_1_txt").innerHeight()
});

$("#box_1_850").css({
  'marginTop': $("#container_1_txt").innerHeight()
});

$("#box_2_850").css({
  'marginTop': $("#container_1").height()
});

$("#box_3_850").css({
  'marginTop': $("#container_1").height()
});

$("#box_4_850").css({
  'marginTop': $("#container_1").height()  
});


var x1, x2, x3; //Establish Loading Variables 

$(".name").on('click' , function() { 

  x1=0; //Reset the Loading Variables
  x2=0;
  x3=0;

  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  $('#photo_850').empty();

  $("<img>", { src: 'http://www.klossal.com/' + id + ".jpg" }).prependTo("#photo_850"); 

  $("#name_850").load(id +"_name.txt");

  $("#credentials_850").load(id +"_credentials.txt");



  $("#bio_850_text").load(id +"_bio.txt", function() {

    $("#bio_850_img").css({
    'marginTop': ($("#bio_850_text").innerHeight() /2) -   
    ($("#bio_850_img").height() / 2)
    });

    console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
    x1=1; // Loaded
    animate(); // Attempt Animation

  });

  $("#edu_850_text").load(id +"_edu.txt", function() {

    $("#edu_850_img").css({
    'marginTop': ($("#edu_850_text").innerHeight() /2) -   
    ($("#edu_850_img").height() / 2)
    });

    console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
    x2=1; // Loaded
    animate(); // Attempt Animation

  });

  $("#contact_850_text").load(id +"_contact.txt", function() {


    $("#contact_850_img").css({
    'marginTop': ($("#contact_850_text").innerHeight() /2) -   
    ($("#contact_850_img").height() / 2)
    });

    console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
    x3=1; // Loaded
    animate(); // Attempt Animation
  });






});




function animate() {

  if((x1===1) && (x2===1) && (x3===1)){ //Animate if all thre divs are loaded



  $("#container_1").animate({
     'height': 87 + $("#box_2_850").outerHeight() + $("#box_3_850").outerHeight() + $("#box_4_850").outerHeight()
  }, 300);

  $("#container_1_txt").animate({
     'margin-top': $("#container_1_txt").innerHeight() * -1
  }, 300);

    $("#box_1_850").delay(160).animate({
     'marginTop': 15
  }, 300);

    $("#box_2_850").delay(330).animate({
     'marginTop': 0
  }, 450);  

    $("#box_3_850").delay(450).animate({
     'marginTop': 0
  }, 450);  

    $("#box_4_850").delay(570).animate({
     'marginTop': 0
  }, 450); 

 }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, and I really appreciate the in code comments!

Comment: @loriensleafs No worries...there has been many times I would have killed for some one on one help! Ahhhhh....